# custom keyboard extension image copied but not paste automatically from keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

i have created custom keyboard with image buttons. when click on image button its copied and paste to message box in any application. I have faced issue is image copied to pasteboard but not paste automatically. Once i have copy and clicking message box for get pasteboard options like select, select all, paste. after clicking paste button image pasted. I need click button in keyboard to send image in message box

i have used this code...

```
let pb = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
let image: UIImage = UIImage(named:String(self.imgArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)))!
let imgData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
pb.setData(imgData, forPasteboardType: UIPasteboardTypeListImage[0] as! String)
self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(pb.string!)
```

Comment: You can't paste image automatically to any application! You must have to do it manually

Comment: @kb920 is right, as the names of `textDocumentProxy` and `insertText` implies; it's only for text based insertions. Instead you'll have to communicate some message to the user to tell them to paste manually into the input box — you'll notice a lot of GIF keyboards etc do this.

Comment: if any paste button action available? I have add paste button in custom keyboard. once image copied click paste button to paste. is this possible?

Comment: if above one is possible..give sample